# One of my friends deposited £42 into my account that he had borrowed previously. Will it affect my UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

One of my friends deposited £42 in my account that he had borrowed previously.  Will it affect my UK visa process? It shows in my bank statement. Is the entry clearance officer only concerned about large deposits? Should I mention it in my cover letter?

Comment: From where was the money borrowed? Why did he deposit this amount? Was it for money he owed you, or a different reason?

Comment: I withdrew cash and gave it to him. He later deposited the money. Money was for his personal use. Deposited in the sense He transferred money to me through online banking.

Comment: Compared to you normal salary/spending, what is 42 pounds? If it is a significant chunk of your monthly income it might raise eyebrows but if you have the kind of income for a trip to the UK then it shouldn't even register.

Comment: Going a step beyond @Borgh's comment, I'd expect that if £42 is significant enough for the officer to wonder/care where it came from you're likely to be rejected for insufficient funds anyway.

Comment: Had to look it up. £42 is approximately $50 USD or $70 CAD.  Adds perspective to the other comments and answers.

Comment: Not an Immigration Officer, but IMO having friends and a social life in your home country would make it appear less likely that you have immigration intent. It's a weak signal; owning a house and having a job are better predictors. But it doesn't hurt.

Comment: What it does show is that you have a connection to the country (namely, one or more friends; like @trollster's flatmates). If elsewhere in the application you have a statement that you have zero connections to the UK and are purely on business, you'd be in trouble! Otherwise, as it's an insignificant amount (maybe enough for the Heathrow Express to London and back to Heathrow, not much else).

Comment: @user3445853 Your comment doesn't make sense to me. Are you assuming that the friend who deposited the money into their account lives in the UK? There's no indication that that is the case in the question that I can see.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the following kinds of transactions in my bank statements that I submitted for my UK Visa Application a few months back:

1) 200 euros from a friend who had borrowed money from me

2) Around 80 euros from another friend for whom I bought some stuff from Amazon

3) Some random amounts ranging between 0-100 euros from ex-flatmates for various purposes like paying in restaurant, some trips, and so on

None of them had any proper explanations while transferring. They just transferred the amount they owed.

After a lot of contemplation, I refrained from providing any explanations. Given my healthy salary and normal expenditure, these transactions from my friends did not look abnormal at all to me.

PS: I got my visa!

Comment: If someone is worrying about one or a couple meager transactions of 42-100  euros/pounds, than they have bigger problems to begin with (too low on savings).

Answer (score 40):

**Don't worry**. 42 pounds is not a material amount of money when judging a visa application, and the officers are looking for regular income (salary etc), not one-offs.

For comparison, an oft-quoted (but AFAICT totally unofficial) guideline is that you want to have funds of around 100 pounds for every day that you're staying in the UK.

Comment: guess it would be a different thing if it were say .. 42,000 GBP (or more) ... I think this will bring up questions about what you intend to do with that amount ..